# How can I sort nested list by determined the element?

Tags: python, python-3.7

### I have a list:  `M = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[5,1,2,4,3]]` and when I want to sort the (M[1],M[2]) only M[2] is sorted not both and when I run in interactive prompt it was print ([2,3,4,1],none)

````
> M[1],M[2].sort()
([2, 3, 4, 1], None)
> M
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]```
````

Comment: You aren't calling `sort` on `M1` even.  You are creating a `tuple`

Comment: try ```print(sorted(M[1]), sorted(M[2]))```

Comment: how I creating a tuple the type of (M) is list

Comment: @mrxra it work, thanks for your help